# Codeigniter force all traffic to specific controller and method

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, routes

I am sorry if this is a duplicate but after hours of searching the interwebs i am drawing up a a blank...

I am trying to remove force all traffic to a specific controller and method so my url will read one thing but be another. the end result would be something like this:

```
https://www.domain.com/home/pages/about
```

Would become this:

```
https://www.domain.com/about
```

I have tried using the routes to no avail. Do not get me wrong, I have the default set to use that route and the main page loads just fine but sub-pages do not follow it and give a 404 error.
Default route:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/pages';
```

One of the many variations I have tried:

```
$route['home']['pages'] = 'home/pages';
```

Is this possible through the routes?

Comment: I think you did not [CI-2](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) and [CI-3](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) documentation. You will get lots of example there how you can solve this.

Comment: That's why in my answer below I stated that I reread the manual one last time and it made sense, This post was so that I could answer it since I had already solved my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting this because 30 seconds before I was about to submit this I read something on another page (the codeigniter manual) that I missed before...

The fix to this is to add a custom route like follows:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/pages';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/pages';
```

That along with the default route forces all pages to use the home controller and the pages method. It gives nice pretty URL's.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to override 404's, for example you are DB powered system with base slugs in the URL:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/pages';
$route['404_override'] = 'home/pages';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/pages';
```